# How to get a SKU price and display it in a TextView

Tags: android, textview, in-app-billing

I need to retrieve the price of my InApp Purchase and display it as a Title in my Card Layout.

This is how the card looks like, instead of "sku price", I need to have the actual price.

[image: this is the card]

I have only this IAP so I shouldn't need an array or a list.

For implementing in App Billing I followed [Android Developers - In App Billing Guide](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html)

So far I tried to write this inside my `onQueryInventoryFinished()` method, without any luck.

```
IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inv) {
        //have we been disposed of in the meantime? if so, quit
        if (mHelper == null) return;

        //is it a failure?
        if(result.isFailure()) {
            alert("Failed to query Inventory: " + result);
            return;
        }

        String skuPrice = inv.getSkuDetails(SKU_PREMIUM).getPrice();
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.card_buy_title)).setText(skuPrice);

        //do we have the premium upgrade?
        Purchase premiumPurchase = inv.getPurchase(SKU_PREMIUM);
        isPremium = (premiumPurchase != null && verifyDeveloperPayload(premiumPurchase));
    }
};
```

As far as I was able to understand this thing I did should get the price of already purchased items. So maybe that is why it does not work.

Can anyone of you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your mHelper setup you have to query all inventory by calling

```
mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, allSkus, null, mGotInventoryListener);
```

where allSkus is a list of all skues.

Check [IabHelper](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/blob/master/TrivialDrive/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/trivialdrivesample/util/IabHelper.java#L606).

Comment: Thank you for the Answer